# SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 Subscription is sent to incorrect email address

Tags: ssrs, subscription

When using a data driven subscription to return a list of recipients the emails sent out are addressed to **username**@mail.domain.com instead of **username**@domain.com. The query in the data driven subscription picks up the **username**.

How can this be changed so that reports are sent out to the correct email address?

It looks like the value in the SMTPServer section of the configuration file is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the DefaultHostName tag in the rsreportserver.config file, restarted the service, and now it all works fine.